# Only count SQL entry if two rows (as a pair) have the needed conditions

Tags: sql, database

How can I only count the "Great" per "Country" in this SQL table?

My table "**commentmeta**"

| comment_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 540 | Voting | Great |
| 540 | Country | UK |
| 560 | Voting | Great |
| 560 | Country | PL |
| 610 | Voting | Bad |
| 610 | Country | UK |
| 630 | Voting | Great |
| 630 | Country | UK |

The result should be
**UK: 2** times "Great",
**PL: 1** time "Great"

With something like this I just get the allover count (all "Greats", not per country):

```
<?php global $wpdb;
$votes = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'country' AND meta_value = 'UK'" );
echo '<div class="votes">'. $votes .'</div>';?>
```

How to combine it with the "comment_id" to get the connection between "Voting" & "Country", so that I can count it per country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following to get all counts:

```
Select T.meta_value As Country,
       COUNT(Case When D.meta_value = 'Great' Then 1 End) As Result
From
(
  Select comment_id, meta_value
  From commentmeta
  Where meta_key = 'Country'
) T
Join commentmeta D
On T.comment_id = D.comment_id
Where D.meta_key = 'Voting'
Group By T.meta_value
```

Also, you may try the following to get the count for a specific country:

```
Select COUNT(*) Reslut From commentmeta T
Where T.meta_value = 'Great' 
And T.comment_id in (Select D.comment_id From commentmeta D Where D.meta_value = 'UK')
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c518102d12d1a6b44a9cd180cb4d03cb).

Comment: Big thx for your help & sry for my late reply! The second one works perfect for me, but with the first one I have some problem. It seems like, that wordpress have some special codex for this case, because with "$wpdb->get_results" I only get "Array" as statement / result. Do you have an idea for the first one that it also works with WordPress?

Comment: You are welcome, the first query returns a set of rows and two columns, not a single value as the second one, you may try something like this: `$votes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT... ;
foreach($votes as $row) {echo 'Country: '.$row->Country', Count: '.$row->Result.'<br/>';}`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the WordPress snippet, that did the trick. So, big thx for your great support! Have a nice day.